# how to avoid characters turning into unicode in R

Tags: r, unicode, rvest

When scraping text data with rvest packaging, sometimes special characters like apostrophe or single quotation mark will turn into unicode
like  which takes time to clean up, is there any way to avoid this and show original characters in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider trying `guess_encoding(x)` and then `x <- read_html(path, encoding = "The best encoding guess")`. Atlernatively you can look at `repair_encoding()` to make correction a posteriori.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. tried ISO-8859-1 (best guess) and UTF=8, somehow doesn’t work but no big deal